# How to Execute a cmd or sh file in the ssh

Tags: cmd, hosting, web-hosting

I have just got some domain hosting and I am wondering how to execute a CMD or a `.sh` file.

I am attempting to make a game server but the software requires me to execute the file. The file managers are rubbish and I have a Nexus 7 that can do FTP. I think I missed something just let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Try `sh /path/to/file.sh`

Comment: -bash: sh /beta/start.sh: command not found is what came back from that.

Comment: Make sure it's executable by using `chmod +x /beta/start.sh` and then running the `sh /beta/start.sh` command

Comment: what does the +x mean?

Comment: The x stands for eXecutable

Comment: I tried to but the file manager that controls chmods doeent like doing it with.sh files and the console seems to not like many commands.

Comment: These are just bssic commands. Are you in root mode? If not, try the su command first and then type the root password. I don't see any other way.

Comment: When I try to run the file start.sh it comes back with start.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable

Comment: You aren't running `file start.sh` are you? You should run `sh start.sh`. Otherwise I think there's something wrong with the file format. Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

You must set executable permission to the .sh file in order to execute it in console.

First of all I am not sure if you could execute it with a cli ftp connection to the hosting.

You must connnect via ssh, then cd the directory where the .sh file is, then change the permission.
If you only want to execute the file, and you don't care the code, then give only execute permission to the file for your user with: `chmod 100 file.sh` then execute it with `./file.sh`

If you want to read the code, then `chmod 500`, and if you want full perms for your user then `chmod 700` make any combination to give or deny perms for users in your own group, or for others.

Comment: when i do the ./file.sh it comes back with "-bash: ./file.sh: command not found"

Comment: if you execute this command: `echo $TERM` what is the output?
Anyway, open de file.sh with a text editor and checkout it the first line is something like `#!/bin/bash`